# Browserify breaks Youtube iFrame API

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube-api, browserify, youtube-iframe-api

When I Browserify a script that acquires and apply's the Youtube iFrame API, `onYoutubeIframeAPIReady()` does not run, and the requested video does not load. Is there a way around this? Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my script:

```
var Command = require('../model/command.js');
var Control = require('../model/control.js');
var User = require('../model/user.js');

var socket = io();

var executions = {};
executions[1] = function() { player.playVideo(); };
executions[2] = function() { player.pauseVideo(); };

var control = Control();

var now = function() { return new Date().getTime() / 1000; };

var user = User();

var update = function() {
  control.room = $('#name').text();

  if (user.last) {
    if (user.command.date > user.last) {
      player.seekTo(user.command.time, true);
      executions[user.command.state]();
      control.last = user.command.date;
    }
  } else {
    player.seekTo(user.time, true);
    executions[user.state]();
    control.last = now();
  }

  control.time = player.getCurrentTime();
  control.state = player.getPlayerState();

  socket.emit('control', control);
};

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    playerVars: {
      'controls': 1,
      'rel': 1,
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  $('#youtube-controls').show();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.Playing) {}
}

$('#youtube-controls').hide();

// Control
$('#pause').click(function() {
  player.pauseVideo();
  control.command = Command(2, player.getCurrentTime());
});

$('#play').click(function() {
  player.playVideo();
  control.command = Command(1, player.getCurrentTime());
});

// Input
socket.on('update', function(message) { user = message; });

// Output
setInterval(update, 1000);
```

Comment: Can You provide code sample?

Comment: I added the script that I browserified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function must be located in the global scope so it has be to defined on the `window` object.

So in your case with browserify you need to define it on the `global` object:

```
global.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    playerVars: {
      'controls': 1,
      'rel': 1,
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}
```